# upload image using angular and spring boot into postgres

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I'm trying to upload image into database sql, at first i add column into database called photo and the data type is varchar(100) then in post contrller i do this  :

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<Invoice> addInvoice(@RequestBody InvoiceDTO invoice , @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {

    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    invoice.setPhoto(fileName);
    Invoice savedInvoice = invoiceService.saveInvoice(invoice);
    String uploadDir = "user-photos/" + savedInvoice.getId();
    FileUpload.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, multipartFile);
    LOGGER.info(" invoice saved  " + invoice.getSerialNumber() + "and id : " + invoice.getId());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(savedInvoice, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

and i create **FileUpload** class to and this is what it's contains :

```
public class FileUpload
{
    public static void saveFile(String uploadDir, String fileName,
                                                    MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);

    if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
    }

    try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
        Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
        Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, ioe);
    }
}
}
```

and in angular form i do this :

```
<div class="addreq">
  <form class="form" [formGroup]="addstudentform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <h1 class ="header" > Add new invoice </h1>

    <input formControlName="serialNumber" type="number" placeholder=" serialNumber "><br>
    <input formControlName="status" type="text" placeholder=" status"><br>
    <input formControlName="customerSerialNumber" type="text" placeholder="customer serial number"><br>
    <input formControlName="employeeSerialNumber" type="text" placeholder="employee serial number"><br>
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />

    <button  (click)="onSave()" type="submit" class="main-btn"> Save</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

and this is my typescript :

```
export class AddInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {


  addstudentform: FormGroup = this._formbuilder.group({
    serialNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    status: ['', Validators.required],
    customerSerialNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    employeeSerialNumber: ['', Validators.required],

});

constructor(private _formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _http: HttpClient
) { }

ngOnInit(): void { }

onSave(): void {

    let serialNumber = this.addstudentform.get('serialNumber')?.value;
    let status = this.addstudentform.get('status')?.value;
    let customerSerialNumber =this.addstudentform.get('customerSerialNumber')?.value;
    let employeeSerialNumber = this.addstudentform.get('employeeSerialNumber')?.value;


    let body = {
      serialNumber: serialNumber,
      status: status,
      customerSerialNumber: customerSerialNumber,
      employeeSerialNumber: employeeSerialNumber
    }
    console.warn(body);

    this._http.post("http://localhost:8085/invoice/save", body).subscribe()


}
}
```

and all of this not working and return error:

> error: "Internal Server Error" message: "Current request is not a
> multipart request"

help please..

Answer (score 0):

The 'save' endpoint expects a form to be posted in the request and in your Angular component you send JSON data. What you have to do is update your Angular component and send a multipart request by using  **FormData**:

```
var formData:any = new FormData();
formData.append("serialNumber",this.addstudentform.get('serialNumber')?.value);
formData.append("status",this.addstudentform.get('status')?.value);
formData.append("customerSerialNumber",this.addstudentform.get('customerSerialNumber')?.value);
formData.append("employeeSerialNumber",this.addstudentform.get('employeeSerialNumber')?.value);
formData.append("photo",this.addstudentform.get('photo')?.value);
this._http.post("http://localhost:8085/invoice/save", formData).subscribe()
```

and in your HTML you have to change:

```
<input formControlName="photo" type="file" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: Where exactly I should put FormData? Should I delete the whole code? or just inside on save function?

Comment: Just replace the code inside the save function.

Comment: now it's returning this error `error: "Unsupported Media Type"
message: "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFZbs09Q5ZeJfqiJR;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
path: "/invoice/save"`

Comment: and this `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'photo'`

Comment: You need to add the FormControlAttribute at the image input

Comment: And update the backend with the answer of @marc-stroebel

Answer (score 0):

using multipart request as described in the answer you'll also need to modify the controller method according to the form params.

```
addInvoice(@RequestParam(name='serialNumber') String serialNumber,
@RequestParam(name='status') String status,
/** add other params... */
 @RequestPart(name='photo') MultipartFile photo) throws IOException {
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests